# How to create and place a .env file in Kafka cluster so a Kafka Connector Config can reference it

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-connector

I’m trying to create a kafka-connector from kafka to snowflake using the kafka to snowflake section of this [tutorial](https://rmoff.net/2019/11/20/streaming-data-from-sql-server-to-kafka-to-snowflake-with-kafka-connect/).

Here is a full sample of the connect config that I'm starting with, contained in a curl request. As you can see it references `${file:/data/credentials.properties:ENV_VAR_NAME}` multiple times to grab envars:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
    http://localhost:8083/connectors/sink_snowflake_01/config \
    -d '{
        "connector.class":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max":1,
        "topics":"mssql-01-mssql.dbo.ORDERS",
        "snowflake.url.name":"${file:/data/credentials.properties:SNOWFLAKE_HOST}",
        "snowflake.user.name":"${file:/data/credentials.properties:SNOWFLAKE_USER}",
        "snowflake.user.role":"SYSADMIN",
        "snowflake.private.key":"${file:/data/credentials.properties:SNOWFLAKE_PRIVATE_KEY}",
        "snowflake.database.name":"DEMO_DB",
        "snowflake.schema.name":"PUBLIC",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeAvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"https://${file:/data/credentials.properties:CCLOUD_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST}",
        "value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source":"USER_INFO",
        "value.converter.basic.auth.user.info":"${file:/data/credentials.properties:CCLOUD_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_API_KEY}:${file:/data/credentials.properties:CCLOUD_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_API_SECRET}"
    }'
```

My question is: How do I put a .env file in “data/credentials.properties” on  within the cluster, so that my connect config will be able to access the env vars within the .env file, using “${…}” syntax like this line of the example connect config json:

```
"snowflake.url.name":"${file:/data/credentials.properties:SNOWFLAKE_HOST}",
```

Comment: The file goes on each of the Kafka Connect workers, not the Kafka cluster

Answer (score 2):

Robin's tutorial (thankyou for the link) makes specific reference to that credentials file:

> All the code shown here is based on this github repo. If you’re following along then make sure you set up .env (copy the template from .env.example) with all of your cloud details. This .env file gets mounted in the Docker container to */data/credentials.properties*, which is what’s referenced in the connector configurations below.

So if you're using his repo, then that file is already dropped in the right spot for you, as you can see at https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/pipeline-to-the-cloud/docker-compose.yml#L73

Comment: Ah I see that now, thanks a bunch!